# Get the address space of a dynamic loaded library

Tags: c, linux, ld

Can anyone help me with finding out how can I obtain the address space of a dynamically loaded library?

The context:
I'm loading a shared library using `dlopen` and at some other point I want to track down `malloc` calls, but only these which were triggered by this library.

What I'm doing right now is in the `malloc` hook I have, I'm going through the whole callstack (obtained by `backtrace`) and using `dladdr` I'm checking each function pointer to see if it comes from my shared library or not, but it's extremely slow.

I thought that maybe if I care only about the one lib which I'm loading manually I can just get its address space, like it is in the memory maps output:

```
$ cat /proc/2049/maps | head
00400000-007a8000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 526896    /usr/bin/python3.5
009a8000-009aa000 r--p 003a8000 08:01 526896    /usr/bin/python3.5
...
```

and see if the function address from the callstack is contained in this address space? It should be much faster I guess... How can I do that? Maybe I can get `.text` symbol address of the lib using `dlsym` (since I care only on address of the executable code), but how calculate the size then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your interposed functions, you can use `uintptr_t  caller_address = (uintptr_t)__builtin_extract_return_addr(__builtin_return_address(0));` to obtain the address of the caller.

To find out which addresses are from which ELF files, either parse `/proc/self/maps`, or use [`dl_iterate_phdr()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dl_iterate_phdr.3.html). For example:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <link.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static int iterator(struct dl_phdr_info *info, size_t size, void *data)
{
    const char  *name;
    size_t       headers, h;

    /* Empty name refers to the binary itself. */
    if (!info->dlpi_name || !info->dlpi_name[0])
        name = (const char *)data;
    else
        name = info->dlpi_name;

    headers = info->dlpi_phnum;
    for (h = 0; h < headers; h++)
        if ((info->dlpi_phdr[h].p_type == PT_LOAD) &&
            (info->dlpi_phdr[h].p_memsz > 0) &&
            (info->dlpi_phdr[h].p_flags)) {
            const uintptr_t  first = info->dlpi_addr + info->dlpi_phdr[h].p_vaddr;
            const uintptr_t  last  = first + info->dlpi_phdr[h].p_memsz - 1;

            /* Addresses first .. last, inclusive, belong to binary 'name'. */
            printf("%s: %lx .. %lx\n", name, (unsigned long)first, (unsigned long)last);
        }

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (dl_iterate_phdr(iterator, argv[0])) {
        fprintf(stderr, "dl_iterate_phdr() failed.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    ...
```

Comment: I can't just use the caller address; if the shared lib called some function in other lib and it involved malloc (like calling dynamically linked boost::ptr_vector i.e.), I want to track it too.

But the `/proc/self/maps` and `dl_iterate_phdr()` ideas are looking good! Will test them and put the results here. I mean, I didn't even think about just "brutal" parsing the file I meant as a good example what I'm looking for :) But maybe that's the way. But first I will check `dl_iterate_phdr()`, seems to be what I was looking for. Many thanks!

Comment: @toshie: Then track the entire call chain. You don't necessarily need a dedicated library; you can do it (up to a fixed depth limit) using [`__builtin_return_address()` and `__builtin_frame_address()`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Return-Address.html).

Comment: Yes, of course you're right. I can check the call chain changing `level` variable. I've tested also `dl_iterate_phdr()` and it works for me. Thanks!